# Hyperledger Composer - Not getting console.log messages

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

For some reason, I've stopped getting console.log() messages to the dev javascript browser console.

I'm running HyperLedger Composer locally on a Mac.

My Current Environment - 
`├── composer-cli@0.19.1
├── composer-playground@0.19.1
├── composer-rest-server@0.19.1
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.19.1
├── npm@5.6.0
├── wscat@2.1.1
└── yo@2.0.2`

Otherwise I'm operating fine.  I reinstalled the fabric-tools directory, and restarted the playground. No change.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling playground and re-installing ?

Comment: What is your question exactly? I think that error has something to do with webpacking the composer modules in playground. I certainly see the same error in the console but I don't think it causes any actual problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Playground with a 'Web' profile then you will see console.log output in the Browser Console.

If you use Playground to connect to your 'real' Fabric, then the console.log output of your Transaction Processing logic will be in the log of the Chaincode container.  This can be viewed with a command similar to `docker logs dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic-sample-network-...`  The output might be quite long so you might want to redirect it to a file for searching or pipe it into grep.

Comment: I can see my containers with Kitematic, the console.log messages aren't being deposited there. I can see   [DEBUG], [INFO], etc. messages, but I'm looking for the console.log messages that I've got in my code. I know I had this working at one point.

Comment: I have just tested this in the logic of the Trade/Tutorial Network sample using v0.19 of composer, and I can see output from my console.log in the chaincode container.  Maybe adding a test console.log at the start of your transaction with just a literal string will help.